# Density or area based heatmap or contourmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I  have one image given
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi14N.png) and I have centroids and area of every small and big defect present here, for example I have three lists x, y and area where x and y are coordinates of centroids of defect(every yellow object considers defect) in the image and area is area of defect computed from contour. I want to show density map or heatmap on this image where it is clearly shown that defect with higher area is having more peak compare to defect with lower area, how can I do this in python? for reference I have attached one more image from one paper given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Kzh.png), here based one kde and weighted kde of image it is clearly shown where bigger defect(big yellow circle) is having more area.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to draw a heatmap superimposed on an image, to represent what you are calling the "defects" in the image (it's not clear from your explanation what those are--maybe deviations from a reference image?)? This sounds like it would be VERY confusing for a viewer to interpret, having to mentally separate the heatmap pixels from the pixels of the image itself. Much better would be to create a new blank image with the same dimensions as the original, then plot points in that image whose center (x,y) represent the location in the original image, and whose radius/color represent area.

Comment: I have modified my question based on your comment and also added one reference image